# Mutations - batch creation of objects

Tags: graphql, graphene-python

I want to use graphene to create many people in one go.
The document only mention the way to create one person like this:

```
class CreatePerson(graphene.Mutation):
class Input:
    name = graphene.String()
    age = graphene.Int()

ok = graphene.Boolean()
person = graphene.Field(lambda: Person)

@staticmethod
def mutate(root, args, context, info):
    person = Person(name=args.get('name'), age=args.get('age'), mobile=args.get('mobile'))
    ok = True
    return CreatePerson(person=person, ok=ok)
```

are there any ways to get it done?

Comment: FYI you can post your solution as an answer and accept it so people coming after you can easily see the final solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can figure out a solution base on the answer of [Jan Hančič](https://stackoverflow.com/users/185527/jan-han%c4%8di%c4%8d)

There is a type called `graphene.InputObjectType` to use in this case

The solution can be

```
class PersonInput(InputObjectType):
    name = graphene.String()
    age = graphene.Int()

class CreatePeople(graphene.Mutation):
    class Input:
       people = graphene.List(PersonInput)

    people = graphene.List(lambda: Person)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, args, context, info):
        people = [Person.objects.create(name=person.name, age=person.age) for person in args.get('people')]
        return CreatePeople(people=people)
```

Comment: I created a mutation this way but I can't find a way how to write a graphql query for this. How do you do that?

Comment: @KarinaKlinkevičiūtė you can find the answer here - https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/queries/

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using a mutation that creates a list of objects, you can also call a mutation that creates one objects *multiple times in one GraphQL request*. This is accomplished using [*GraphQL Aliases*](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases):

```
mutation {
  c001: createPerson(
    name: "Donald Duck"
    age: 42
  ) {
    id
  }

  c002: createPerson(
    name: "Daisy Duck"
    age: 43
  ) {
    id
  }

  c003: createPerson(
    name: "Mickey Mouse"
    age: 44
  ) {
    id
  }
}
```

Comment: the link to the FAQ is dead.

Comment: which one is better, the batch of list or batch of alias?

Answer (score 4):

Make your mutation input a list and return a list of created people. Something like this:

```
class CreatePerson(graphene.Mutation):
    class Input:
        name = graphene.List(graphene.String)

    ok = graphene.Boolean()
    people = graphene.List(Person)

    @staticmethod
    def mutate(root, args, context, info):
        people = [Person(name=name) for name in args.get('name)]
        ok = True
        return CreatePerson(people=people, ok=ok)
```

Comment: great! but how can I deal with more than one field. E.g. name, address and age for the person?

Comment: You can have complex input types, see the docs: http://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/types/mutations/

Comment: Hi Jan, I use the InputObject and it worked but the data was not saved to the db. Would you mind helping on this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Receive a list of input, create all instances and return them all

The model node/type should be like-

```
class UserType(DjangoObjectType):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        interfaces = (CustomGrapheneNode, )
        filter_fields = {}
        only_fields = (
            'name',
            'email'
        )
```

Define Input fields

```
class UserInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    name = graphene.String(required=True)
    password = graphene.String(required=True)
```

Mutation class

```
class CreateUser(graphene.Mutation):
    users = graphene.List(UserType)

    class Input:
        data = graphene.List(UserInput)

    Output = graphene.List(UserType)

    def mutate(self, info, data):
        users = []
        for item in data:
            user = User.objects.create(name=data['name'], 
                                       password=data['password'])
            users.append(user)
        return users
```

make this mutation callable by main schema

```
class Mutation():
    create_user = CreateUser.Field()
```

the Mutation Query view will be as -

```
mutation{
    createUser(data:[{name:"john", password:"1234"},
                     {name:"john", password:"1234"}]) {
        user{
            name
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: good solution. Just to add you could use the bulk_create() method  there in the mutate() function as described in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/

Comment: in case someone else tries this answer and you run into error, in the mutate function just change for item in data:
            user = User.objects.create(name=data['name'], 
                                       password=data['password']) to instead: for item in data:
            user = User.objects.create(name=item['name'], 
                                       password=item['password'])